$ f:X\to Y $ is continuous on $ X $ iff $ \forall A\subset X $, $ f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)} $.
I have always thought this result as a generalised version of the sequential criterion of continuity. Surely, $ \bar{A} $ contains all the convergent sequences from $ A $, and the result says that the functional images of those sequences is also convergent in $ f(A) $. However, when I am trying to prove this in Real Analysis, I am not able to complete the sufficient part. Following is my incomplete attempt:

Theorem: $ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $ is continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $ if $ \forall A\subset \mathbb{R} $, $ f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)} $.

Incomplete proof: Fix $ x\in\mathbb{R} $ arbitrary. Let the sequence $ \{x_{n}\} $ converge to $ x $. We will show $ f(x_{n})\to f(x) $.
Call the set $$ A=\{x_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}. $$ Then $ x\in\bar{A} $. If $ A $ is finite, then $ \{x_{n}\} $ is an eventually constant sequence, thus so is $ \{f(x_{n})\} $, converging to $ f(x) $; trivially proving our claim.
Now, consider the case when $ A $ is infinite. By the hypothesis, $ f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)} $. Hence $ f(x)\in\overline{f(A)} $. Therefore, there exists a subsequence $ \{f(x_{p})\} $ of $ \{f(x_{n})\} $ converging to $ f(x) $. $ \blacksquare $
I am not able to conclude that the entire sequence $ f(x_{n})\to f(x) $.
Does this approach actually take you to the result? Or is there any fundamental misunderstanding in my interpretation of the result?

Why does it only follow that a subsequence converges and not the sequence itself?

This question is a duplicate of A map is continuous if and only if for every set, the image of closure is contained in the closure of image, and Where does the notion of first countability is used? How does $f(\bar{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ happened?, and many others.

See also this question that would finish your proof.

I am not sure if the way you are trying to prove this will work. Here is another approach.
Let $A$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the pre-image $f^{-1}(A)$. If sequence of $x_n \in f^{-1}(A)$ converges to $x$, then $x \in \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$. Since $f(\overline{f^{-1}(A)}) \in \overline{f(f^{-1}(A))} = \overline{A} = A$, we have $f(x) \in A$, therefore $x \in f^{-1}(A)$. Thus we proved that pre-image of a closed set is closed, which means $f$ is continuous.

Please avoid posting answers to duplicate questions.

@MartinBrandenburg, sorry didn't know it is duplicate.

Yeah after almost 15 years of existence every general and basic math question is now a duplicate. Not every one has to be closed as a duplicate, but totally standard characterizations of continuous functions, for sure.

Got it, thank you!
